# remove parent <li> if child <>ul <li> not found

Tags: php, jquery

i am generating menu dynamically using php in my project in ul li.
menu are generating as follows.

```
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
    <li class="toproot"><a href="#"><i class="user"><span>User</span></i></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="some link">Create User</a></li>
           <li><a href="some link">List User</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

   <li class="toproot"><a href="#"><i class="user"><span>Group</span></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="some link">Create Group</a></li>
            <li><a href="some link">Group List</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </li>

     <li class="toproot"><a href="#"><i class="user"><span>Settings</span></i></a>
        <ul>
            <!--links are not generated here -->
        </ul>    
    </li>                   

</ul>
```

now the problem is that i want to remove third li of `setting main menu` beacause of it has no `submenu`.
i searching for jquery code for this implementation. i have use php to display or display not main menu. `but want to implement in jquery/js`.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('.topmenu li.toproot:not(:has(ul))').remove()
```

Comment: a problem is in above code that if we see the page source code then it shows that menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can code somthing like this, using jquery.

```
if ($('#mylist li').length == 0){
Do Code for removing elements
}
```